# how to retrieve file request type in jsp sending from ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I want to upload an image using JSP and ajax in which all uploaded file validation. I'm checking via jQuery and you can see in code before success function code. and this file information I want to retrieve in the JSP page. this ajax code sending file details which I want to upload to the target JSP page. if ajax is sending normal input text field data, we can retrieve it via `request.getParameter()` in JSP page but how to retrieve file input response.

```js
var file;

$("#updatepictureform").submit(function(event) {
    $("#updatepicturemessage").hide();

    //show spinner
    $("#spinner").css("display", "block");
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!file) {
        $("#spinner").css("display", "none");
        $("#updatepicturemessage").html('<div class="alert alert-danger">Please upload a picture!</div>');
        $("#updatepicturemessage").slideDown();
        return false;
    }
    var imagefile = file.type;
    var match = ["image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/jpg"];
    if ($.inArray(imagefile, match) == -1) {
        $("#updatepicturemessage").html('<div class="alert alert-danger">Wrong File Format</div>');
        $("#updatepicturemessage").slideDown();
        $("#spinner").css("display", "none");
        return false;
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: "updatepicture.jsp",
            type: "POST",
            data: new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,

            success: function(data) {
                if (data) {
                    $("#updatepicturemessage").html(data);
                    console.log(data);
                    //hide spinner
                    $("#spinner").css("display", "none");
                    //show message
                    $("#updatepicturemessage").slideDown();
                    //update picture in the settings
                } else {
                    location.reload();
                }

            },
            error: function() {
                $("#updatepicturemessage").html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>There was an error with the Ajax Call. Please try again later.</div>");
                //hide spinner
                $("#spinner").css("display", "none");
                //show message
                $("#signupmessage").slideDown();

            }
        });
    }
});
```

This is the output I am getting when printing file information at ajax page.

```
Array{[picture]=>Array{[name]=>myprofile.jpg [type]=>image/jpeg [error]=>0 [size]=>276599 }}
```

Comment: Array{[picture]=>Array{[name]=>myprofile.jpg     [type]=>image/jpeg      [error]=>0     [size]=>276599    }} when i am printing file information at ajax page this output i am getting .